Couple sleeps in a film room during catastrophe from space
The plot: A girl, maybe older teenager, is sleeping with her boyfriend in a secure film room when some catastrophe from space covers the earth with bad stuff. I think her boyfriend goes outside and is killed by those remaining who are all weirded up. She finds her younger sister and eventually a healthy guy (becomes the new boyfriend). One scene is in a shopping mall or big store like Macy;'s. The government is working on a fix and wants their blood for serum. At some point they are in a radio station. The rain washes away all of the bad stuff. Anyone know the title?

Night of the Comet (1984) starring Catherine Mary Stewart and Kelli Maroney.
OP hits almost every plot point in Wikipedia plot summary in his question:

Starts in a movie theater projection room
Boyfriend dies by monsters
Sister shows up
Radio station
Another boy
Mall
Scientists trying to make a cure from them
Rain cleans stuff up


Definitely it is this movie. 80s classic.

For sure this is it.
